# JUnit 4: Test case returns an object used in other tests in the test suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have created several tests cases for my application, all these are chained in a single test suite class.

However, i would like to pass an object created in the first test to the others.

To be clearer, the first test tests a class that creates a complex object with data coming from my database. I would like the others to test the methods of the object itself.

Here is how i define my test suite class:

```
package tests.testSuites;

import tests.Test1;
import tests.Test2;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    Test1.class
    Test2.class
})
public class DataTestSuite {    
}
```

But I would like to have something like this somewhere:

```
MyObject obj=Test1.testcreation();
Test2.testMethod(obj);
```

How can I combine a regular JUnit testSuite class definition with the need to pass the created object to my other test?

**EDIT**

For information, the test suite is launched in a test runner class. This class helps formatting the results and creates a custom log file.

This is how it calls the test suite:

```
public class MetExploreTestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Result result=JUnitCore.runClasses(DataTestSuite.class);
        if(result.wasSuccessful()){
            System.out.println("All tests succesful ");
        }else{
            for(Failure failure:result.getFailures()){
                System.out.println(failure.toString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to use @Parametrized annotation - http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html?

Comment: If you don't recreate the objects that you use for testing for every test, you have the risk if creating order-dependent tests (because the previous test may have changed the state of the object). Better to create your test object for every test I believe.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: That's good point. In that case Before annotation to create object should be used. However if you are getting the object from the database it's no longer unit test, but rather integration test.

Comment: I've looked into the @Parameterized annotation, but i didn't find it really helpful for this problem as it is used in the test case class and not in the test suite class. if it is possible to use in test suites, i didn't find any documentation on that.
For the database, it's actually a replica of our database only used for testing and storing test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I found what I was looking for.

The library JExample allows you to create dependencies between different tests and to pass arguments between them which is what I needed. http://scg.unibe.ch/research/jexample

I really recommend it.

Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that. Each test should be independent of the others. You can then run tests singly, to debug them, and each test is easier to understand. Also, JUnit runs tests in an arbitrary order; you can not guarantee that the object will be created before it is used.

If several tests use a similar object, consider extracting the code for creating it into a shared private method of the test class. If many tests use the object, consider making it a test fixture set up by a @before method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Rule instead of reuse some data from one test to the others. You can see an example of use here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules

That rule can create that big object and then you can use it in every test you want.

I don't recommend you to create any dependency between tests because things could change in the future and you'd have to change many things in your other tests.

If you really want to do what you said, there is an annotation @dependsOn that would be usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing integration testing instead of unit tests.

What you can do is to:

1. Create mock class that connects to your database and creates this complex object
2. Write a new class that will run all your tests and will create an instance of your mock class  (this might be helpfull http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm )
3. Create methods with @BeforeClass annotation that will get this object.
4. Run your tests.

For my point of view it is not very practical, and not unit test at all. Unit tests should be independent, and do not rely on other tests.

Comment: I actually have a testrunner class that launches the test suite and logs the results in an appropriate file but I don't know how to pass the created object to the test classes within the runner.

Answer (score 0):

Why not factor out the creation of `MyObject` to a utility class?

```
 public class Test2{
    ...
    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
        MyObject obj = TestUtil.createMyObject();

        //do test here

    }


 }
```

You can then call the `TestUtil.createMyObject()` from any test.  Also if creating `MyObject` is expensive, you can lazily create it and cache the result or use any of the other patterns useful for factory methods.